# How can mkdir() succeed but set wrong permissions?

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-safety, file-permissions

I have a problem with a piece of Linux code (written in C++) that does something like this:

1. Create a new directory with mkdir("xyz",0755) which succeeds (return code is 0).
2. Tries to open/create a new file in the justly created directory.
3. Fails because the permissions on the new directory is actually 0600 and NOT 0755 as requested.

The code looks like this and checks that the path prefix "/tmp/slim" exists before coming to this part:

```
int somefunc(const string& path)
{
  if ( mkdir( path.c_str(), 0755 ) == 0 ) {
    // (*) if (!access( path.c_str(), F_OK | R_OK | W_OK | X_OK ) == 0 )
    // (*)   chmod( path.c_str(), 0755);
    string pidinfo = to_string( getpid() ) + "\n";
    string pidinfofile = path + "/pid";
    int fd = open( pidinfofile.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR );
    if ( fd == -1 )
      return 0;
    ssize_t written = write( fd, text.c_str(), text.size() );
    // ... do more stuff
  }
}
```

As this snippet of a strace (no lines missing/redacted) shows, the openat() fails even though the mkdir() returned 0.

```
13661 16:32:22.068465 mkdir("/tmp/slim/testsock", 0755) = 0
13661 16:32:22.068720 getpid()                = 13661
13661 16:32:22.068829 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/slim/testsock/pid", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The result of running getfacl looks like this:

```
[localhost]$ getfacl /tmp/slim/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp/slim/
# owner: stk
# group: stk
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

How can the the mkdir() return 0 but create a directory with permissions that differ from the specified? It's not a umask thing, I've tried setting umask to 0 before creating the directory without any effect. If the two commented lines marked with (*) is enabled/uncommented, things work as they should - but I don't like that sort of symptom treatment that skirts the real problem. There's got to be a reasonable explanation for this seemingly weird behavior.

Part of the story is that this works in an application with multiple threads. Each thread performs the code above (which is a smallish, thread safe function), and most threads succeed, but there's always 1 or 2 (out of 5-10) that fails as described.

Comment: Couldn't you simply chmod right after you create the directory?  I see that you're doing that in a commented-out line.

Comment: `and most threads succeed, but there's always 1 or 2 (out of 5-10) that fails as described.` -- Then it's not really thread-safe, is it?

Comment: Please match code to logs (open() is called on a folder currently), and possibly include an example we could test?

Comment: By the way,  using `O_RDWR` for directory should fail with `EISDIR`. [open(3): open file - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open)

Comment: Indeed I could, as I've noted. But I really don't like to gloss a seemingly defect system call without knowing the underlying cause.

Comment: The underlying cause is almost certainly a thread safety problem.  You can verify that by forcing single-threaded execution and running it several times.

Comment: Sorry about the open(directory) snafu - the code sample's been updated.

Comment: What does `getfacl /tmp/slim` show?

Comment: @Robert Harvey Well some of the threads fail because a system call seemingly behaves badly. But the function as shown is thread safe (all state, apart from the file system, is on each thread's stack). I also suspect this is a thread related issue, but if that's the case there is some hidden, shared state somewhere. And I was hoping that somebody had some insights as what would cause mkdir() to behave oddly.

Comment: @IanAbbott I have update the question with output from getfacl.

Comment: @ZiggyMax Thanks, nothing suspicious there.

Comment: My insight is: Post a [mcve].

Comment: What you're asking for requires in-depth knowledge of Linux internals.  Hopefully someone here has that (I certainly don't).  I suppose you could try looking at the source code.

Comment: I solved my problem, see the update in the question. Thanks to everyone who took time to read my question and post suggestions.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks, I have done that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as it turned out (and quite expectedly, right?) it was a threading problem alright, as @RobertHarvey also hinted at. But I was also a bit right :-) when I wrote in a comment "there is some hidden, shared state somewhere". Well, the process umask is a shared, but perhaps not exactly hidden, state/variable. Here's what went wrong:

1. One or more threads was executing the code above, happily creating directories.
2. Simultaneously another thread was fiddling with the umask to ensure the right permission of a Unix socket it was creating, temporarily setting umask at 0177.
3. Although the umask fiddling was ever so short, Murphy's Law dictated that the directories sometimes were created exactly while the umask was 0177, also forcing the directories to get permission mask 0600 rather than 0755.

L*esson (re-)learned:* Watch out for hidden shared state/variables when using more than 1 thread.